# Search similar value in another table using IN (SQLite)

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite to deal with tons of data (like 100gb of data).

I need to seach the value of one column in other table in the fastest way possible. 
For example, I need to find the following values of Table 1

```
[COD]
C62
K801
```

And then find them in Table 2:

```
[COD_2]
C60-C63
K80-K81
```

My desired result is something like:

```
[COD_1]  [COD_2]
 C62      C60-C63
 K801     K80-K81
```

Since I have a lot of data, it is inefficient to do something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_1, TABLE_2
WHERE COD_1 LIKE '%' || COD_2 || '%';
```

Instead, I was trying to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE COD_1 IN (SELECT COD_2 FROM TABLE_2);
```

Of course that this doesn't result because the codes are not exactly the sames. Is there a way to search for similar values of one column (something like the LIKE operator) in other table by using IN? Or other way that doesn't cross TABLE_1 and TABLE_2?

Thank you!!!
useful to me.

Comment: Are you trying to store a range in a single value (Bad idea, btw)? If so, how is `K801` in `K80-K81`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the small data set shown, and my presumed answer to @Shawn's question (K801 is a typo and is meant to be K80 or K81) I assume the following problem description:

Find a row in COD_2 such that the value in COD_1 is *between* `{value1}-{value2}` in COD_2; the `-` being significant and dependable.

I cannot speak to speed, but I would approach it this way:

```
SELECT value1, value2
from COD_1,COD_2
where value1 between substr(value2,1,instr(value2,'-')-1) and substr(value2,instr(value2,'-')+1)
```

The thought being: split the value from COD-2 into a "start" and an "end" value.